# Deleting the last TWO characters if they fit certain requirements in R

Tags: r, substring, gsub

I want to use a function to go threw strings and only replaces the last two characters if they match certain criteria. How can I do that?

I tried

```
cleantable3 = gsub('.{2}$', '', cleantable2)
```

but then it always deletes all the last two. Lets say I only want those replaced that contain " D| E"

Thank you all!

Comment: You need a grouping construct for multicharacter alternatives, `gsub('(?: D| E)$', '', cleantable2)`. Here, you may also use ``gsub(' [DE]$', '', cleantable2)`` as both start with space.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression isn't good '.{2}$' means it will match any(.) 2 characters at the end of string($).
You haven't defined the question very well, but in your case I think this is the regex expression you need '(D.$)|(E.$)|(.D$)|(.E$)'. So this is the desired code.

```
cleantable3 = gsub('(D.$)|(E.$)|(.D$)|(.E$)', '', cleantable2)
```